# Filtro na Datatable com Radio Box

Tags: datatable

Sou iniciante em Jquery, e estou tentando apresentar na minha `DataTable` um filtro que, ao clicar na Opção do `Radio`, filtrar apenas os registros daquele `Value`.

Ex: Ao clicar no `Radio` com `Value` "Active", a função do javascript mostre no `DataTable` apenas os que estiverem com esse status, mas não tou sabendo onde estou errando, alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

**JS:**

```
var oTable;
var cRotina = '';

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn-group .btn").click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).find("input").val();
    if (inputValue != 'all') {
      var target = $('table tr[data-status="' + inputValue + '"]');
      $("table tbody tr").not(target).hide();
      target.fadeIn();
    } else {
      $("table tbody tr").fadeIn();
    }
  });

  // Changing the class of status label to support Bootstrap 4
  var bs = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION;
  var str = bs.split(".");
  if (str[0] == 4) {
    $(".label").each(function() {
      var classStr = $(this).attr("class");
      var newClassStr = classStr.replace(/label/g, "badge");
      $(this).removeAttr("class").addClass(newClassStr);
    });
  }

  oTable = $('#tabela_rotinas').DataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bStateSave": false,
    "sAjaxDataProp": "server",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "paging": false,
    "sAjaxSource": "http://192.168.222.252:8082/WSSERVICES",
    "sServerMethod": "GET",
    "searching": false,
    "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
        "dataType": "json",
        "type": "GET",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": {
          cRotina: cRotina
        },
        "success": fnCallback
      });
    },
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      "aTargets": [1],
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        if (data == "Executando") {
          return '<tr data-status="active"><td><span class="label label-success">' + data + '</span></td></tr>';
        } else if (data == "Parado") {
          return '<tr data-status="expired"><td><span class="label label-danger">' + data + '</span></td></tr>';
        } else if (data == "Inactive") {
          return '<tr data-status="inactive"><td><span class="label label-warning">' + data + '</span></td></tr>';
        }
      }
    }],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "nome"
      },
      {
        "mData": "status"
      },
      {
        "mData": "local"
      },
      {
        "mData": "porta"
      }
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
      "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
      "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
      "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
      "sInfoPostFix": "",
      "sInfoThousands": ".",
      "sLoadingRecords": '<center><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></center>',
      "sProcessing": "Processando...",
      "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
      "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
      }
    }
  });

});

setInterval(function() {
  oTable.ajax.reload();
}, 60000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Serviços <b>Protheus</b></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-info active">
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="all" checked="checked"> Todos
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-success">
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="active"> Executando
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-warning">
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="inactive"> Em Pausa
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-danger">
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="expired"> Parados
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tabela_rotinas">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NOME</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>LOCAL</th>
        <th>PORTA</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```